# Running Apache-Kafka as a service on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have an instance on AWS EC2 with Kafka running, messages are published to it from Logstash and consumed also by Logstash  before they are sent to Elasticsearch.

One of the reasons I am using Kafka is in-case any of my ELK pipline goes down/fails, Kafka will keep my data for 1 week, so I am think what happens if Kafka goes down how do I know?

I run Kafka using `nohup ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties > ~/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1 &`

My question, can I run Kafka as a service and if so can you point me to a good resource or how to do.

I have got scripts running hourly monitoring if Logstash is running and emailing me if they go down and I would like to do the same with Kafka.

My logstash are  running as a service.

Thanks

Comment: What I would do is to use systemd units, [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/), etc.

Comment: OK @Luciano Afranllie , think I will go with supervisor.